# Configuring Wifi with Ubuntu 14.04 on hp pavillion 15 laptop

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, bluetooth, realtek-wireless

I am having problems in configuring wifi with ubuntu 14.04LTS on my hp pavillion 15 laptop. Only if the wifi is very close by (such as mobile hotspot) does it detect the network. There is absolutely no issue with windows which is inbuilt, so I think its not a hardware problem. (Ethernet works fine with ubuntu.) The bluetooth also does not pick up devises. Any tips?

Below is what I got by running [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/master/wireless-info)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 20 Jul 2015 16:13 IST +0530

Booted last: 20 Jul 2015 09:42 IST +0530

Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-031600-generic #201408031935 SMP Sun Aug 3 23:36:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

GNOME Flashback (Metacity)

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8096]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57c4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04b3:310c IBM Corp. Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 03f0:ae07 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 18249  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 hp_wmi
rtl8723be              87260  0 
btcoexist              55886  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         23427  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                27306  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                69157  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              687021  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              521225  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19379  3 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.54.158  Bcast:192.168.55.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1409270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:707053 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1757878060 (1.7 GB)  TX bytes:119170359 (119.1 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:169.254.6.213  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"CMI-HOSTEL"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.52.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     1003   0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.48.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 192.168.52.2
nameserver 192.168.52.5
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search cmi.ac.in

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root       856     1  0 09:42 ?        00:00:02 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Ethernet connection 1] ----------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.54.158
    Prefix:          21 (255.255.248.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.52.1

    DNS:             192.168.52.2
    DNS:             192.168.52.5

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723be
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/asankar_Wifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=asankar_Wifi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=asankar_Wifi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR53]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR53 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=NETGEAR53 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Milkyway]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Milkyway | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Milkyway | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CMI-HOSTEL]] (600 root)
[ipv6] method=auto
[connection] id=CMI-HOSTEL | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=CMI-HOSTEL | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[802-1x] ca-cert=/home/kgarun/Desktop/cacert.crt
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/INDIGO]] (600 root)
[connection] id=INDIGO | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=INDIGO | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         PageHe  <page_he@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     C94095C986767A931B924EF
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        22:1A:AC:02:5E:17:C8:E7:6D:81:97:A5:3A:A7:65:A4:61:7A:E7:DC
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     7410431A59C24B1BC33226E
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        22:1A:AC:02:5E:17:C8:E7:6D:81:97:A5:3A:A7:65:A4:61:7A:E7:DC
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     3273ECD6028617EFD27E4F4
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        22:1A:AC:02:5E:17:C8:E7:6D:81:97:A5:3A:A7:65:A4:61:7A:E7:DC
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     8362106E96F806A9DBAE565
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        22:1A:AC:02:5E:17:C8:E7:6D:81:97:A5:3A:A7:65:A4:61:7A:E7:DC
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     E4D3FCB715C0CB33E42D11E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        22:1A:AC:02:5E:17:C8:E7:6D:81:97:A5:3A:A7:65:A4:61:7A:E7:DC
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D86AFD97E7F71C59777C05F
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-031600-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        22:1A:AC:02:5E:17:C8:E7:6D:81:97:A5:3A:A7:65:A4:61:7A:E7:DC
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723be]
debug: 0
fwlps: N
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be fwlps=0

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0xb723 (rtl8723be)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[14495.093743] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 26 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```